# How to throttle processing of parallelized Spring WebClient responses?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive, spring-webclient

I want to execute webservice requests in parallel using spring `WebClient`.

The webservice takes approx 10s to respond, thus I want to send like 20 requests at once. So that 20 requests are always waiting for a response.
But the further processing behind the response should only continue with 4 threads.

Question: how can I achieve this?

I tried:

```
//assume like 2000 requests
List<Object> requests = prepareRequests();

requests.parallelStream().forEach(req -> {
   JsonNode response = webClient.post()
      .bodyValue(req)
      ...
      .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
      .block();

   processFurther(response);
}
```

This would help executing the requests at least to some degree in parallel (depending on cpus) - in my case usually 4.

I continued wrapping the call in a `ForkJoinPool` with 20 threads:

```
ForkJoinPool myPool = new ForkJoinPool(20);
        myPool.submit(() ->
                requests.parallelStream().forEach(req -> {
                    //...same as above
                    JsonNode response = webClient.post()
                       .bodyValue(req)
                       ...
                       .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
                       .block();

                    processFurther(response);
                })
        ).get();
```

That works, **but** as soon as the response returns, it will be processed. Thus, theoretically, if all 20 requests return at once, all of them will be further processed by 20 threads.

Question: how can I throttle the further processing to less threads, like 4?

Comment: i would stick the list in a `Flux` and do each request in a `flatMap` and then do a `limit(4)` and place it on its on `Scheduler` with say only 4 workers, and `flatMap` again. This way you wont have a lot of idling threads waiting for responses, and no setup time for parallelising things on multiple cores (which is completly unnecassary as multiple core work usually is only a benefit if having cpu heavy tasks)

Comment: Could you give a code example?

Comment: no i can't. Instructions are there, and you should be able experiment yourself and come up with the code.